# i create a game in python. i am looking to make it in a constant loop until user decide to cancel

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, game-development

Hey guys I create a rock paper scissor game using python and i would like to loop it after game ends. please, what shall I add to my code?

here is my code Replit, thanks

https://replit.com/join/ansgpehgvc-anasmizhar

Comment: Please fix your spelling and add more details. You probably won't get an answer like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your final code lines should be like this:

```
while(True): 
  choices = get_choices()
  if choices['player'] == "stop": break 
  result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])
  print (result)
```

`choices` is a dictionary, so your option is equal to `choices['player']`
If your option is equal to the string `stop`, the loop breaks.